# How to describe the dissipation of tension between two people?

Tags: word-choice

I'd like to describe the sense of two people, one who is angry (call him Joe) at another (call him Bob), but upon hearing Bob's retort, Joe reconsiders his position and changes his mind about being angry.

How would you describe such a scene in terms of Joe's body language during this change?

One idea I was to describe how his tense limbs loosened, but I can't think of a concise, elegant way of describing that.

Comment: *tension lifting off* or even *clouds of doubt lifting away*

Comment: I think it's fairly appropriate as it's a word choice question; I have a scenario I'd like to describe and I'm not sure if there exists a verb or idiom that describes the scenario. But I'll check there anyway, thanks.

Comment: It's *not* fairly appropriate as a word choice question, nor as a single word request question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply "he relaxed" or "his body relaxed". Relax is the word that precisely describe a physical tension loosening, in common language, but also in medical term, as well as describing a state of mind, or a situation defusing. From Webster:

> > To relieve from nervous tension...
> >
> > To slacken or make less tense or rigid...
> >
> > To cast off social restraint, nervous tension, or anxiety...

Actually, I've just realized that you asked two different questions: 1) the dissipation of tension between two people 2) describe Joe body language when the tension is dissipating. I'm answering No 2 here..

Answer (score 1):

You could try "detente", especially if they were arguing politics.